# Can we create external table on top of adls2 from data bricks using interactive cluster?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I'm trying to create external table on top of adls2 from azure data bricks and in location I gave "abfss://......". This is not working and throwing the below error

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: shaded.databricks.xxxxx.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.ConfigurationPropertyNotFoundException Configuration property xxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net not found.);;
```

If I'm giving mount point path in the location it is working as expected. Is there any other way we can create the table without the mount point?

Comment: You may checkout similar issue addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56792095/create-external-table-in-azure-databricks/56832261

Comment: Following up to see if the above suggestion was helpful. And, if you have any further query do let us know.

Comment: Thanks @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT, I was able to create the table by giving the path in the options

Comment: Would you like you post that as an answer so you can mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I figured out that we can create an external table by giving full path in the options.

Example of creating parquet table

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
(column1 int,
column2 int
)
USING PARQUET OPTIONS (PATH "abfss://container@storageAccount/.....")
```